# Union(range) value fails vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set an array to the values of non consecutive arrays.

My code

```
With WBInfoProduit.Sheets(1)
Set myrange = Union(ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, ProdNameCol), Cells(rows, ProdNameCol)), ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, FundNameCol), Cells(rows, FundNameCol)), ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, CompagnieCol), Cells(rows, CompagnieCol)))
```

End With
So the array is supossed to have 3 columns , but it only has 2 when I check with the debbuger.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I missed this:   TableInfoProduit = myrange.Value

Comment: Could you post more of your code? It's hard to see what exactly is happening without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. Your code

```
    With WBInfoProduit.Sheets(1)
        Set myrange = Union( _
                  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, ProdNameCol), Cells(Rows, ProdNameCol)) _
                , ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, FundNameCol), Cells(Rows, FundNameCol)) _
                , ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, CompagnieCol), Cells(Rows, CompagnieCol)) _
                )
    End With
```

Be aware that every "Cells" is referring to the cells on the activesheet.
So

With WBInfoProduit.Sheets(1)

does nothing!

I tried this:

```
Sub xxx()


    Dim myrange As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set myrange = Union( _
                  .Range(.Cells(1,  5), .Cells(100,  5)) _
                , .Range(.Cells(1, 10), .Cells(100, 10)) _
                , .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(100, 20)) _
                )
    End With

    Debug.Print myrange.Address

End Sub
```

It resulted in this output

```
 $E$1:$E$100,$J$1:$J$100,$T$1:$T$100
```

So as long as ProdNameCol, FundNameCol, CompagnieCol in your code are set to different values it should work but possibly only on the active sheet.

HOWEVER,

If you are trying to assign ranges to an array you need to be aware of range areas!

See the code below which will help

```
Sub xxx()


    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim MyArray() As Variant

    Dim MyArray1() As Variant
    Dim MyArray2() As Variant
    Dim MyArray3() As Variant
    Dim MyArray4() As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        Set myrange = Union( _
                  .Range(.Cells(1,  5), .Cells(100,  5)) _
                , .Range(.Cells(1, 10), .Cells(100, 10)) _
                , .Range(.Cells(1, 20), .Cells(100, 20)) _
                )
    End With


    Debug.Print myrange.Address
    Debug.Print myrange.Areas(1).Address
    Debug.Print myrange.Areas(2).Address
    Debug.Print myrange.Areas(3).Address

    MyArray = myrange
    MyArray1 = myrange.Areas(1)
    MyArray2 = myrange.Areas(2)
    MyArray3 = myrange.Areas(3)


    ' MyArray4 = Union(MyArray1, MyArray2, MyArray3)

End Sub
```

The MyArray4 line will nto work see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588913/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-in-vba) for help with this!