# How to concatenate multi arrays into 1 array in Exel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have several worksheets in an Excel and each of the worksheets contain 1 Form.
I have grouped similar forms into an array in order to apply a function across all relevant worksheets.

```
FORM_01 = Array(FORM001.Name,FORM_001_001.Name)
FORM_02 = Array(FORM002.Name, FORM_002_001.Name)
```

Can I concatenate `FORM_01` and `FORM_02` into a new consolidated array like this?

```
FORM_combine =Array(FORM001.Name,FORM_001_001.Name,FORM002.Name, FORM_002_001.Name)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Merge two Arrays in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588913/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
FORM_01 = Array("a", "b")
FORM_02 = Array("c", dD")
FORM_combine = Split(Join(FORM_01, Chr(1)) & Chr(1) & Join(FORM_02, Chr(1)), Chr(1))
```

This will give `FORM_combine` as `("a", "b", "c", "d")`

Got this from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/484250-how-concatenate-two-1d-array-vba.html).